# Connecting app to RabbitMQ cluster through MassTransit. AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have the following situation:

- a server named **testServer** where my RabbitMQ cluster is located.
- cluster name:  **rabbit@MyCompany-rabbitmq-test-node01**
- in the server there are currently 3 nodes, each one running inside its own docker container. Let's take only one node in example and its container named: **company-rabbitmq-test-node01**
- The ports of this container are correctly open (5672 is the port to contact the node, and 15672 is the port of the plugin)
- Virtual host:

[image]

In my code:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(container.Resolve<SerilogLoggerFactory>());
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host("testServer", hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Username("user-app");
            hostConfigurator.Password("user-password");

            hostConfigurator.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                string[] hostnames = ("testServer:5672;testServer:5682;testServer:5692").Split(';');
                c.ClusterMembers = hostnames;
            });
        });


        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
    }));

});

IBusControl busControl = container.Kernel.Resolve<IBusControl>();
try
{
    busControl.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
    logger.Error("RabbitMQ broker is not reachable, BusControl cannot be started. ", ex);
}
```

PROBLEM: when I try to start the application it says:

> Broker unreachable: testServer:5672/  ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

My user page:

[image]

the **user-app** has access to the virtual host. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you fixed it? Could try ask the question directly to MT at https://gitter.im/MassTransit/MassTransit